# JBoss 6 error deploying Axis2

Tags: jboss, apache-axis

I tried to deploy Axis2 war file (versions 1.6.1 and 1.5.6) on JBoss 6.0.0 and got the following error:

`

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///C:/Desenvolvimento/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/
axis2.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundEx
ception: 1.0.com.sun.codemodel.JConditional
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(Dep
loyersImpl.java:1228) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainD
eployerImpl.java:905) [:2.2.0.GA]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.c
heckComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:87) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.che
ckAllComplete(ProfileDeployerPluginRegistry.java:107) [:0.2.2]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceB
ootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:135) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.bootstrap.BasicProfileServiceB
ootstrap.start(BasicProfileServiceBootstrap.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer.startBootstraps(A
bstractServer.java:827) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
        at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.r
un(AbstractServer.java:417) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-5]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_27]
```

`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but with CXF.
The problem is the jar jaxb-xjc-*.jar

I need to add a XML with special configuration for jboss.

File name: **jboss-scanning.xml** (put this in WEB-INF directory)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scanning xmlns="urn:jboss:scanning:1.0">
    <path name="WEB-INF/classes" />
    <path name="WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar">
        <exclude name="" recurse="true" />
    </path>
</scanning>
```

This is the content of my file. Too I need a file with name: **jboss-classloading.xml**, in WEB-INF directory too

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0" domain="project.war"
    export-all="NON_EMPTY" import-all="true">
</classloading>
```

I hope this help, sorry for my poor english.